# Go back programmatically in backstack by custom button click using android navigation graph navigation

Tags: android, android-navigation

So I have an `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` (**A**) that navigates to `androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat` (**B**) using:

```
findNavController().navigate(ADirections.actionAToB())
```

B then navigates to another `androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat` (**C**) using:

```
findNavController().navigate(BDirections.actionBToC())
```

In **C** I have a button that when clicked should navigate back (in the backstack?) to **B**. Now **C** should not exist any more (the data represented by **C** is destroyed).

On **C**:s clicklistener I have tried (without success):

```
findNavController().navigateUp()
findNavController().navigate(CDirections.actionCToB())
findNavController().popBackStack()
this@C.parentFragmentManager.popBackStack()
```

All of those options navigate me to **A** instead of **B**.

The back arrow (the OS back option) works when in **C** by going back to **B**.

**------ Edit Add nav graph ---------**

In my question I missed one level of settings views but the problem is the same ... **A** is a Fragment, **B** is a PreferenceFragmentCompat, **C** is a PreferenceFragmentCompat and then **D** is a PreferenceFragmentCompat and the place I try to navigate from to **C** (rather then **B** as stated above)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/A">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/A"
    android:name="my.package.A"
    android:label="A"
    tools:layout="@layout/A" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_A_to_B"
        app:destination="@id/B" />
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/B"
    android:name="my.package.sub.B"
    android:label="B" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_B_to_C"
        app:destination="@id/C" />
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/C"
    android:name="my.package.sub.C" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_C_to_D"
        app:destination="@id/D" />
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/D"
    android:name="my.package.sub.D"
    android:label="D" />
</navigation>
```

Comment: Please include your navigation graph and specifically your `<action>` associated with `actionBToC`

Comment: @ianhanniballake Thanks for your feedback. I've added the graph